# Is it possible to make images in a folder non browsable in site directory using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, directory, file-permissions

So is it possible to make images in a folder non browsable even if a person has a direct link to an image? and make the page 404 or something if they try to view it ? (yet still display the image in a html page).

using .htaccess IF its even possible or something other way.

Comment: If it sounds stupid My reason is a webgl game that shows images for the score so I need to hide the images so people can't get a hold of the image urls and change the image in dev tools yet still have the images display in the .html/js. (I've already hid them well in the js this is about being extra safe). :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with this `.htaccess` in your images folder:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.your_domain_name\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Or for global site:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.your_domain_name\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(?:gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$ - [NC,F]
```

But you have to add files extensions

Comment: File signatures meaning extensions i.e .jpg .png etc? If so can this include js files ? and thank you for the reply :)

Comment: Yes, sorry, Mac user ;-) You can add all extensions you like.

Comment: \.(?:gif|png|jpg|jpeg|js|css)$ like this?